# Cardinality of a set of polynomial

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, \exists b_0, \ldots, b_m \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ with } b_m \neq 0 \text{ and } b_mx^m + \cdots + b_0 = 0\}$. Im trying to find cardinality of A. One of the hints given were to write the set as a set of unions to get rid of quantifiers. Although I have no idea what sets would you even take a union of. Another thing that I thought about is that if $m$ is fixed, the by rational root theorem there are $m$ roots of the equation so would that imply that its cardinality is at most $m$? What would I have to include in the proof to make it formal since my arguments are just informal observations? Also just to confirm, in the set A, the $m$ is fixed right?

EDIT: would the unions would be the union of sets $A_i$ for $i \in \{0,1,\ldots, m\}$ where $A_i = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: i \in \mathbb{N}, b_0, \ldots, b_i \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ with } b_i \neq 0 \text{ and } b_ix^i + \cdots + b_0 = 0\}$? The idea being that the unions of $A_i$ will have overlaps so it is at most $m$.

Comment: I don't know how to derive it but it is obvious that $A=\mathbb{\bar Q}$, And $|\mathbb{\bar Q}|=\aleph_0$.(The cardinality of the set of algebraic numbers is countably infinite)

Comment: What is the $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ notation?

Comment: What propreties must the $b_i$ have? Real numbers? Rationals? Integers?

Comment: @derreckthomas. $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}$ is the set of algebraic numbers.

Comment: @IgorRivin I fixed it. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a set $P_m=\{b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m: b_m\ne0 \text{ and $b_i\in \mathbb Z$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,m$}\}$

Define $f_m:P_m\to \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\cdots \times\mathbb Z$ ($m+1$ times) by $f_m(b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m)=(b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_m)$. Now prove that $f_m$ is bijection and this proves that $P_m$ is countable.
Therefore, $P=\cup_{m=1}^\infty P_m$ is also countable. So let $P=\{\beta_1(x), \beta_2(x),\cdots\}$, where $\beta_i(x)$'s are polynomials.

With this understanding, your $A=\cup_{i=1}^\infty\{x\in \mathbb R: \beta_i(x)=0\}$.

Now Use this hint to prove $A$ is countable: Every polynomial of degree $m\in \mathbb N$ has $m$ roots, which may be complex or real.

Comment: can't we just show injectivity alone? Since $\mathbb{Z}^{m+1}$ is countable and if $f_m$ is injective then $P_m$ is countable as well.

Comment: @derreckthomas: That would be enough in this case by Cantor-Bernstein- Schroder theorem.

Comment: Can you confirm if my injective function is correct. I defined $g_m: \mathbb{Z}^{m+1} \rightarrow P_n$ such that $g_m(b_0, \ldots, b_n) = (b_0 + \cdots + b_nx^n)$?

Comment: @derreckthomas: That's correct but does not prove that $P_n$ is countable. Simply write an injective from $P_n$ to $\mathbb Z^{m+1}$.

Comment: yeah i proved there is an injection both ways and use cantor-schroder-bernstein to conclude that they have equal cardinalities. And then I proved that $\mathbb{Z}^{m+1}$ is countable and thus $P_n$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a countable set o polynomials with integer coefficients, so the union of their sets of roots is at most countable. On the other hand, each rational number is a root of such a polynomial (of degree 1, but also of whatever degree you want), so the number of such roots is at least countable. So, countable it is.